# Pass array of information from angular to asp net controller that takes in model object

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, entity-framework

I'm getting an array returned from an API call. The array looks something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7SYW.png.

I get the array, then call my controller method using this

```
this.http.post<Maps[]>(this.baseUrl + "api/Map/InsertMap/", beatmaps[0]).subscribe();
```

`Maps` being an interface

```
interface Maps {
Id: number;
Name: string;
Artist: string;
Creator: string;
}
```

Now I just have a basic insert controller method

```
        [Route("api/[controller]/InsertMap/")]
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AsyncCreateMap(MapModel model)
    {
        await _mapService.AsyncInsert(model);

        return Ok();
    }
```

It takes in the Model as a parameter and then inserts it using Entity Framework. It doesn't work. I have no idea how to actually transfer the array I get to an object I can use in my controller.

Here is my whole controller class

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MapController : Controller
{
    private readonly MapService _mapService;

    public MapController(MapService mapService)
    {
        _mapService = mapService;
    }

    [Route("api/[controller]/Maps")]
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AsyncMaps()
    {
        var data = await _mapService.AsyncGetMaps(0, 10);

        return Ok(data);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AsyncCreateMap([FromBody]MapModel model)
    {
        await _mapService.AsyncInsert(model);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Exception? `model` is null? Controller is not hit? Something else?

Comment: I get this error: `POST https://localhost:44311/api/Map/InsertMap/ 404`
But it can't be 404 as I have defined it. @Crowcoder

Comment: Sorry to break it to you, but it can be because it is. I suggest for testing you remove the Route attribute and see if you can hit it with the default route.

Comment: Could be related to mixing routes, why do you have `[action]` on `HttpPost`? and also `Route`?

Comment: I've done as you said, changed it around and the same problem still occurs. `POST https://localhost:44311/api/Map/AsyncCreateMap/ 404`. I've updated the OP with my controller class.

Answer (score 1):

you should try use [FromBody].

Example:

```
public class ModelDTO
{
    public string Id{get; set;}
    public List<string> Childs {get; set;}
}


[HttpPost]
[Route("api/nice/Save")]
public bool Save([FromBody] ModelDTO model)
{ ...
```

in the angular side, you should use httpClient.post..

```
save(data: IData): Observable<ISaveCompleted> {
    const options = this.createPostOptions();
    const saveCompleted = this.http
    .post(options.url, data, options)
    .map((res: Response) => <ISaveCompleted>res.json());
    return saveCompleted;
 }
```